# write variable to session and return it in another request

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am trying to create a progress bar using PHP. Basically the "main" request loops through thousands of items and on each item, it keeps updating session. And another request returns the session variable every couple seconds through ajax. However, I am having trouble with writing to the session because it writes everything at the end of the loop. Here is the code:

```
// main request
$total = count($state_logs);
foreach($state_logs as $i=>$stateLog) {
    $subject = $stateLog->subject;
    $subject->processState($stateLog);
    $_SESSION['invoice_progress_current'] = $i/$total;
}
$_SESSION['invoice_progress_current'] = 1.0;

// progress request
$current = $_SESSION['invoice_progress_current'] * 100;   
echo json_encode(['current'=>$current]);
```

What can I do to make the session write on every loop iteration?

Comment: Are you using `session_start` at the top of your scripts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely because session files are locked while they are being written to. This is why we have the [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/session-write-close) function, to indicate that we are done with session data and the next request may proceed. Of course, this won't work in your case.

In a situation like this, it may be worth manually implementing something. For instance, you could write to a file with the session ID as the filename, indicating the progress. Since you have control over opening and closing the file, you can then have the second request read from it without locking issues.

Comment: Do you think the same would be possible with memcached or redis?

Comment: Memcache, certainly. Redis, I'm not familiar with.